# confusion with the email newsletter

Tags: html

i was trying to get a newsletter done in html . is it mandatory to use  while creating a newsletter email template ? what else do I need to take into account to encode the newsletter ?

Comment: Your question is not really answerable at this point. What do you mean? What do you mean by template? What language/platform are you using?

Comment: i have to get the newsletter in the form of an email .. gotta use pure html ...

Comment: Do you have a design already?

Answer (score 1):

To get started you can use the templates provided [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/). When you have some time on your hands go [here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/code-html-email-newsletters) to understand more about the difficulties associated with creating HTML email.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is whether you need HTML to make a newsletter. If it's not please ignore my answer.

You don't *need* to use HTML for your email newsletter, you can just use plain text. However if you want to markup your email newsletter (have colors, images, etc) you do need HTML.

Properly doing HTML-email is difficult. I'm guessing you're not an HTML expert, so I'd advise you to either keep to plain text (which for most purposes is absolutely fine) or use an email newsletter service like [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/).

Comment: i can code in html but not quite sure of how to use that in emailing newsletters ....

Comment: So this transforms your question into "how do I make an HTML email?", right? That's a broad question, and I suggest you search for a tutorial or guide. Sitepoint has a [book](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/htmlemail1/) on it. But I'll repeat myself: HTML in email is difficult, try a service first.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an application to send your html newsletter from.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com has an easy to use user interface as well as a free trial.